# Understanding change of variables

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

So there's this one thing I can't wrap my head around.

The problem is:

Use the change of variables $x = \sinh u$ to compute the indefinite integral
\begin{equation*}
    \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
\end{equation*}

Solution:

\begin{align*}
    \frac{dx}{du}=\sinh'x=\cosh x 
\end{align*}
$$\iff$$
\begin{align*}
    \int \frac{\cosh x}{\sqrt{1+\sinh^2x}}\,du = \int \frac{\cosh x}{\sqrt{\cosh^2x}}\,du = \int\frac{\cosh x}{\cosh x}\,du= \int 1 \,du = u + C = \sinh^{-1}x+C
\end{align*}

and I understand every step except the first one, $\frac{dx}{du}=\sinh'x$. I'm just generally confused when it comes to change of variables and how to use the Leibniz notation to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's clearer if you use *differentials*: remember the differential of a function $f$ of the variable $u$ is defined as the formal expression
$$\mathrm df=f'(u)\,\mathrm du, $$
where $\mathrm du$ (the differential of the variable) represents symbolically a small increment of the variable, and $\mathrm df$ (the differential of the function) is an approximation of the corresponding increment of $f(u)$, as measured along the tangent line.

This being said, the substitution $x=\sinh u$ yields the differential of $x$:
$$\mathrm dx=\cosh u\,\mathrm du, $$
and we have to express the whole *differential form* $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ in function of $u$ and its differential. Therefore, the integral becomes
$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\to \int\frac{\cosh u\,\mathrm du}{\sqrt{1+\sinh^2u}}=\int\frac{\cosh u\,\mathrm du}{\cosh u}=\int\mathrm du=u=\operatorname{argsinh}x.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $x=\sinh(u)$, so you have $$\frac{dx}{du}=\frac{d}{du}\left(\sinh(u) \right)=\cosh(u)$$
It's the same that you write $$x=\sinh(u) \implies x'=\cosh(u)$$
However, the second notation it's not recommended for when you are integrating because this may be confused you.